# Andengine project status

Tags: andengine

I am in the process of starting with Android development and thought of using andengine.

But when looking in github it seems like the project has been not-so-actibe the last 6 month.

Any comments on this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the development status of a particular library at a particular point in time, not a programming problem involving its use.

Comment: We are also working with engine and provide support to other member as active members.

Answer (score 0):

It working well and active and awesome. If you wanna start with that, just go!